# converting jsonstring to java object

Tags: java

I am trying to convert Json String into Java Object. It is working for other inputs just for one input its not working. Is their any other way to do this?

My code:

```
JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();
JsonObject sel=parser.parse(selectedTerritory).getAsJsonObject();
TmsMapItBuilderBean dataSet = new Gson().fromJson(sel, TmsMapItBuilderBean.class);
ArrayList dataList = dataSet.getResultList();           
resultMapData = mapServiceDelegate.processAssetDataWithGeoCodeForTerritories(subId, dataList);
```

It shows the following error:

```
Error on json convert to object :com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object near
ddress' :'2500 LEE'S CHAPEL RD',   "stat
```

Comment: Your JSON is illegal.

Comment: So what should I do for that?

Comment: Without seeing your JSON, no one can help with much in the way of specifics.

Comment: @mansi it looks like you might need to change `'2500 LEE'S CHAPEL RD'` to `"2500 LEE'S CHAPEL RD"`...

Comment: @mansi you have a `'` right here: `LEE**'**s`...

Comment: The problem with my json is rather than taking double quotes, it displays data in single quote.

Comment: I have a huge list of data so its not possible for me to change each input json data, Is their any other way for doing that?

Comment: @mansi change the way your JSON is generated. Change the source...

Comment: I am getting all dataset from database and then I am converting that data in to jsonArray in javascript. Later I convert that JsonArray into JsonString and pass that JsonString which is "selectedTerritory" to Java class. Where I am trying to convert this JsonString into Java Object.

Comment: If you use single quotes it's not actually json...

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was my mistake while storing data obtained from database into jsonArray. I gave single quotes for the address. in javascript.

Comment: How are you converting your data? It is clearly not outputting an actual JSON. Based on the error you received, the `..ddress'` field ends in single quote, it's value is enclosed in single quotes, but then the following field, `"stat..." starts starts with double quote.

Comment: It worked now, I removed single quotes to double quotes in javascript for address. It was my bad giving single quotes. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your JSON is broken. You use a character that delimits the field's with which you are encoding your object. Use an escape to encode ' as a string.

Example: 
`{ 'name': 'tom\'s Hut' }`

However as someone pointed out ' are not meant to be used for JSON Objects. I highly encourage you to use double-quotes.

```
{"name": "tom's Hut"}
```

Would be the correct way...

For more information on JSONs see: http://www.json.org/

Comment: Hello Yvonne, Thanks a lot for helping out. Its working now.

Comment: In JSON, single quotes are not used for syntax.